# Prevent Blade from displaying something if JS condition meets

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, syntax, laravel-blade

its simple and complex at the same time :) i know about server client stuff but this one lets me hangin'

What i want to achieve: Display the following piece of code ONLY if it has not been displayed 5 times already.

```
@if(...)
<div class="goal">
   {{ $variable }}
</div>
@endif
```

so i want to achieve something like

```
<script> if($('.goal').length < 5) { </script>
    @if(...)
<div class="goal">
   {{ $variable }}
</div>
@endif
<script> } </script>
```

but well.. it doesnt work ^^" is there any other way? This gets Infinite scroll appended every time so i tried working with local storage but same problem, cant check the if condition.
help is gladly appreciated
Regards
Desory

edit: using jquery.load() function to append so sending data with it is pretty much not the way to go here i guess because i dont want to append this to the url. should i call ajax inside the callback of the load ?

Comment: Remember that Blade is PHP, so it gets processed before it's sent to the browser, so javascript has no effect on it. You'll have to look at a PHP way of doing it, or use Ajax to load/hide after the page is loaded.

Comment: You should do AJAX call because blade is a server-rendered output.

Answer (score 1):

Try using directly accessing your variable and not class as class don't return length of the content,

```
@if(strlen($variable) > 5)
   //code goes here
@endif
```